# jquery .replace(/./g, "") do not work for me but others

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, preg-replace

I found this snippet somewhere and it works like a charm:

```
var n = parseInt(e.find("span.favNum").text().replace(/./g, "")) + 1;
```

If I do it in a similar way it doesn't work anymore.

I do the following:

```
<div id ="test">6.987</div>
var test = $("#test");
var r = test.text().replace(/./g, "");
console.log("wrong ", r);
```

I know that I can replace it also like this:

```
var r = test.text().replace(".", "");
```

This works.

I would like to understand why the "stolen" snippet is working.
Any idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/nJZMf/3/

The original script is found here: http://wp-svbtle.themeskult.com/

You will find the snippet by viewing the source of index.html and searching for `.replace`.

Comment: `.` is a special character in regular expressions. If you want to use it literally, you have to escape it.

Comment: Ahh I see the different now. I changed the komma in the origin-snipe to a point. And this I have to escape. Thx felix

Comment: @hamburger - I took the liberty of editing your question for spelling and English grammar. Hope that's OK. Dein Englisch ist *viel* besser als mein Deutsch! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that the code in the page you linked to works, where yours doesn't, is that it's not the same regular expression. Here's what I found in that page (and similar code in several places)

```
r = n.text().replace( /,/g, "" )
```

where `r` is a jQuery object.

Note that the regular expression has a `,` inside the `//`, not a `.` like the code you had trouble with.

Comma is not a special character in regular expressions, so it needs no special treatment. Period has a special meaning. As the other answers pointed out, it matches *all* characters, and you need to prefix it with `\` if you want to match `.` only.

Also note that `.replace()` is *not* jQuery code, it's JavaScript.

jQuery's `.text()` method returns a JavaScript `String` value. So anything you do with that string - such as the `.replace()` call - is actually a JavaScript `String` method.

The distinction is important when you want to research a problem: a search for "javascript string replace" will get you better information than "jquery replace".

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape the "."

```
test.text().replace(/\./g, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

It has to be `var r = test.text().replace(/\./g, "");` instead of `var r = test.text().replace(/./g, "");` because you need to escape the `.` in order for it to be replaced.

Comment: the origin one works without brackets and is also jquery. I tested it with my jsfiddle. it gives a wrong result.

Comment: @hamburger I read the original question wrong, so I changed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/nJZMf/4/

Solution because I add `\` in `var r = test.text().replace(/\./g, "");`

Comment: you missed the \ :), I edited it so it is now correct like you example fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you did not escape dot.

But keep in mind that:

`.replace(".", "");`

`.replace(/\./g, "");`

are two different things.

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/rmhpkz9n/1/